# How to make CouponParams dynamic

Tags: go, stripe-payments, coupon

I have been working in PHP and I have done this easily in that but currently passing certain code to Go but having some issues.

This below is the parameters definition with go package for stripe

```
params := &stripe.CouponParams{
            Duration:         stripe.String(c.Duration),
            DurationInMonths: stripe.Int64(c.DurationInMonths),
            //PercentOff:       stripe.Float64(c.PercentOff),
            AmountOff:      stripe.Int64(c.AmountOff),
            Currency:       stripe.String(strings.ToLower(c.Currency)), //ISO code for the currency
            ID:             stripe.String(c.ID),
            MaxRedemptions: stripe.Int64(c.MaxRedemptions),
            //Name:           stripe.String(c.Name),
            AppliesTo: &stripe.CouponAppliesToParams{
                Products: c.AppliesTo.Products,
            },
            CurrencyOptions: map[string]*stripe.CouponCurrencyOptionsParams{
                //"eur": {AmountOff: stripe.Int64(9000)},
                "jpy": {AmountOff: stripe.Int64(12000)},
            },
        }
```

in PHP i would just have an array and i could manipulate it easily but with GO and my low  knowledge i am currently stuck.
Is there a way to make this conditionally? I have a few fields obligatory but there are few combinations that i'll need to make.

```
if c.Name != "" {//c is the struct from json body similar to the stripe but used with a validator
        //add it
    }
```

Comment: Your question misses some essential part(s) while apparently concentrating on an inessential one (do we really need the full definition of `CouponParams` to understand what you're after)? I _think_ you wanted to convey that that `c` variable contains a set of fields (being of some user-defined `struct` type) and you would like to have some loop-like construct which would iterate over the fields of `c` and assign the values of the fields which are not empty strings (but you also did not say whether all the fields are of string type) to the same-named fields of the variable being costructed (?)

Comment: Well if i define the CouponsParams with the basic set values that all have, i want to be able to add the optional Fields with some conditions met. Also this was more oriented to people that normally work with stripe. But currently after define the initial i don't know how to add to that.

Comment: found the solution :X dario.cat/mergo does what i want